# Why does OAuth fail when using ASP.NET Identity Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.x project with the following configuration:

```
services
  .AddAuthentication(options => options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticaitonDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddFacebook(ConfigureFacebook);
```

Predictably, when I call from one of my actions:

`return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/test" }, "Facebook");`

... Then, I get navigated through the Facebook OAuth sequence. When I find my way back to my app, `HttpContext.User.Identity` is populated with the relevant details:

- `User.Identity.Name` - The Facebook user name.
- `User.Identity.AuthenticationType` - The string `"Facebook"`.
- `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` - `true`.

This is all well and as is expected. However, if I add to my application configuration the following

```
services.AddIdentity<MyUserType, MyRoleType>()
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>();
```

Suddenly, the OAuth flow ends in `User.Identity` being anonymous without anything else changing. If we drill into IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs, we find:

> options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme =
>   IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme; options.DefaultChallengeScheme =
>   IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme; options.DefaultSignInScheme =
>   IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;

among other things...

What is going on here? Why is Identity interfering with the Cookie process, and what is the correct way to get the User returned from an OAuth provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When combining ASP.NET Identity and OAuth, certain considerations need to be made:

#### Configuring the services:

Adding `AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` is no longer necessary because Identity adds its own cookie handlers.

#### Getting the external user as a ClaimsPrincipal:

If you want the external user to be populated under `HttpContext.User`, do the following:

```
.AddFacebook(options => {
    options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
})
```

After being redirected to the `RedirectUri` in your challenge's `AuthenticationProperties`, your `HttpContext.User` will be populated.

#### Getting the external user as `ExternalLoginInfo`:

This is preferred if you need to know things about the user such as:

1. From what provider did they come?
2. What is their unique key on the provider?

Your services should be configured like so:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddFacebook(options =>
    {
        options.AppId = "";
        options.AppSecret = "";
    });

services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>();
```

In your login controller, inject `SignInManager<TUser>` in:

```
public DefaultController(SIgnInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
```

And in your challenge action, use `ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties` to get the challenge properties:

```
public IActionResult LoginExternal() {
    var props = SignInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties("Facebook", "/");
    return Challenge(props, "Facebook");
}
```

In your return action, use `GetExternalLoginInfoAsync` to get the external details about the user:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginCallback() {
    var loginInfo = await SignInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    // This object will tell you everything you need to know about the incoming user.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For combining OAuth and Asp.Net Core Identity, you need to configure the `facebookOptions.SignInScheme` with `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`.

Try code below:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(options => options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
    {
        facebookOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        facebookOptions.AppId = "xx";
        facebookOptions.AppSecret = "xxx";
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't do the trick. On the return trip back from Facebook (or another provider), the `User.Identity` is anonymous.

Comment: To add to my other remarks, FacebookOptions.SignInScheme falls back to AuthenticationOptions.DefaultSignInScheme and AuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme, so adding that line is irrelevant.